# Is thier a way to log custom statements in Cucumber Extent Reports 4 instead using scenario.write method

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I don`t want to use the Scenario.write method but at the same i need to log my custom statements in Cucumber Extent report.

The Reason why i am asking this question is when i use the scenario.write method it prints all the scenarios statements to all the outputs in extent report as shown in the image attached.

So i am not sure of any other alternative ways to solve my issue and can somebody please pitchin and have look and provide me an solution for this.

Below is my Runner class

```
@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:featurefile" }, glue = { "classpath:com.hal.test.stepdefinition",
        "classpath:com.hal.helper" }, plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/Hal.json",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:" }, monochrome = true, tags = {
                        "@Api"})



public class HalTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
            
    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
            
        ReporterUtil.archiveReport();
                
    }
```

[image]

```
Below is my Pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HAL</groupId>
    <artifactId>HALBRANDS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.22</allure.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.surefire.verion>2.22.0</maven.surefire.verion>
        <io.cucumber.verion>4.2.0</io.cucumber.verion>

    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- <configuration> <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source> <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target> 
                    <fork>true</fork> <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\javac</executable> 
                    </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <propertyName>java.library.path</propertyName>
                        <buildDirectory>src/main/resources/configFile</buildDirectory>
                        
                        <cucumber.options>${cucumber.options}</cucumber.options>
                        
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>2</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/com/hal/brands/test/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId> <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>0.1.6</version> <executions> <execution> <id>send_an_email</id> 
                <phase>test</phase> <goals> <goal>send-mail</goal> </goals> <inherited>false</inherited> 
                <configuration> <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost> <mailport>465</mailport> 
                <mailauth>true</mailauth> <mailssl>true</mailssl> <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig> 
                <mailuser>test12@gmail.com</mailuser> <mailpassword>drv@123</mailpassword> 
                <from>test12@gmail.com</from> <subject>UVS E-commerce Automation Report 
                </subject> <failonerror>true</failonerror> <htmlMessage> <![CDATA[ <p>Hi,</p> 
                <p>Check out the attached test execution report.</p> <p>From,</p> <p>Madhu 
                Golla</p> <p>UVS Automation Team</p> ]]> </htmlMessage> <receivers> <receiver>Madhurrr@gmail.com</receiver> 
                <receiver>test12@gmail.com</receiver> </receivers> <fileSets> <fileSet> 
                <directory>${basedir}/Automation_Report/Reports</directory> <includes> <include>**/Report.html</include> 
                </includes> </fileSet> </fileSets> </configuration> </execution> </executions> 
                </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Cucumber Dependencies -->


        <!-- cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${io.cucumber.verion}</version> -->
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.0</version> -->
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!--cucumber-jvm-deps <dependency> <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.6</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.0</version> -->
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <!-- <version>1.2.6</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.2.0</version> -->
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${io.cucumber.verion}</version> -->
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${io.cucumber.verion}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.cliftonlabs/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cliftonlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId> <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.1</version> </dependency> -->



        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Extent Reports -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0.2</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId> 
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> <version>3.1.2</version> </dependency> 
            <dependency> <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId> <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> 
            <version>2.41.1</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- extentreports-cucumber4-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <!-- io.github.bonigarcia webdrivermanager -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paulhammant/ngwebdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- org.sikuli/sikuli-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- rest-assured-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi -->

    </dependencies>
    <name>HAL Brands</name>
</project>
```

Comment: It is a known issue with extent cucumber adapter and i think this is fixed in the latest versions. try importing latest version in to your POM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave a try with all different alternative possibilities but not nothing worked but just one trick which really worked for me is upgrading the few of the dependencies which are given below

- extentreports
- extentreports-cucumber4-adapter
- cucumber-testng
- cucumber-jvm
- cucumber-core
- cucumber-java

Below is the complete pom.xml for reference

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HalBrands</groupId>
    <artifactId>HalBrands</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>1.4.22</allure.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.surefire.verion>2.22.0</maven.surefire.verion>
        <io.cucumber.verion>4.2.0</io.cucumber.verion>

    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- <configuration> <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source> <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target> 
                    <fork>true</fork> <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\javac</executable> 
                    </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <propertyName>java.library.path</propertyName>
                        <buildDirectory>src/main/resources/configFile</buildDirectory>
                        
                        <cucumber.options>${cucumber.options}</cucumber.options>
                        
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>2</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/com/Hal/brands/test/testng/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId> <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>0.1.6</version> <executions> <execution> <id>send_an_email</id> 
                <phase>test</phase> <goals> <goal>send-mail</goal> </goals> <inherited>false</inherited> 
                <configuration> <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost> <mailport>465</mailport> 
                <mailauth>true</mailauth> <mailssl>true</mailssl> <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig> 
                <mailuser>test12@gmail.com</mailuser> <mailpassword>test@123</mailpassword> 
                <from>test12@gmail.com</from> <subject>E-commerce Automation Report 
                </subject> <failonerror>true</failonerror> <htmlMessage> <![CDATA[ <p>Hi,</p> 
                <p>Check out the attached test execution report.</p> <p>From,</p> <p>Test 
                User11</p> <p>Automation Team</p> ]]> </htmlMessage> <receivers> <receiver>test1113@gmail.com</receiver> 
                <receiver>test12@gmail.com</receiver> </receivers> <fileSets> <fileSet> 
                <directory>${basedir}/Automation_Report/Reports</directory> <includes> <include>**/Report.html</include> 
                </includes> </fileSet> </fileSets> </configuration> </execution> </executions> 
                </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Cucumber Dependencies -->


        <!-- cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${io.cucumber.verion}</version> -->
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.0</version> -->
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!--cucumber-jvm-deps <dependency> <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.6</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.0</version> -->
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <!-- <version>1.2.6</version> -->
        </dependency>

      <!-- cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${io.cucumber.verion}</version> -->
            <!--<version>4.2.0</version>-->
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.2.0</version> -->
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        

        <!-- cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${io.cucumber.verion}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.cliftonlabs/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cliftonlabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId> <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.1</version> </dependency> -->



        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Extent Reports -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId> <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0.2</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId> 
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> <version>3.1.2</version> </dependency> 
            <dependency> <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId> <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> 
            <version>2.41.1</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- extentreports-cucumber4-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <!-- io.github.bonigarcia webdrivermanager -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paulhammant/ngwebdriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- org.sikuli/sikuli-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- rest-assured-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi -->

    </dependencies>
    <name>Hal Brands</name>
</project>
```